# How to trigger different classes in the main class on the Springboot platform?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Springboot and trying to run my java code on this platform first time.
I am using Spring Tools Suite as my IDE.

So, my code hierarchy is like this :

```
PayConsumer.java
-- CreateConsumer.java
```

I am calling CreateConsumer.java inside PayConsumer.java. Now, I need to trigger PayConsumer.java.
I have gone through the documentation and create a new java file as mentioned below :

**ApplicationRun.java :**

```
package com.example.consumer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationRun {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRun.class, args);
    }
}
```

As this is the main class, I need to bind PayConsumer.java somehow here so that when the main class runs, it should trigger the PayConsumer.java also. Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: I personally didn't get your question. What do you mean by bind PayConsumer.java? Would you like to run some methods from PayConsumer.java when your application is bootstrapped?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion !! I couldn't get the wordings right but yes, would to like to run a method of PayConsumer.java when my application is bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to call method from **PayConsumer.java** you can do something like this inside your **ApplicationRun** class.

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
    return args -> {
        PayConsumer payConsumer = new PayConsumer();
        payConsumer.callYourMethod();
    };
}
```

You can also autowire PayConsumer object if it's managed by Spring.

Your final **ApplicationRun** class will look like this.

```
package com.example.consumer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationRun {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRun.class, args);
}

@Bean
CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
    return args -> {
        PayConsumer payConsumer = new PayConsumer();
        payConsumer.callYourMethod();
    };
  }
 }
```